# How do I run an extended overpass turbo query from a script?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have an xml query which starts out like this:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="250">
  <id-query {{nominatimArea:Ridgefield Connecticut}} into="area"/>
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
```

This works fine here: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/5J7

But when I try to query using `wget`, it returns `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request`. If I resolve the query into it normalized form, then it works fine:

```
<osm-script output="xml" timeout="250">
  <id-query type="area" ref="2705805056" into="area"/>
  <!-- gather results -->
  <union>
```

How can I pass the former query through a script, or how can I lookup the area in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the official website for more to correctly use WGET http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html

You can also to get started, try with CURL instead of WGET: it's more easy as you can copy the call you do in browser using the Network panel of your debugger (below illustrated with Google Chrome but available also on FireFox)

[image: Google Chrome CURL copy with OverPass API]

For scripting, this [query Overpass Python library](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper) or this [Node JS package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/query-overpass)
 can be interesting.

Comment: The place_id only matches some of the time. For example, Danbury Connecticut has a place_id of 64246176 and an osm_id of 33271879, but the sends this in the query: <id-query type="area" ref="2433271879" into="area"/>

Comment: place_id is a purely Nominatim internal identifier, it has absolutely no relevance outside of Nominatim, see: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/21542/nominatim-place-id

Comment: ref="2433271879" is derived from OSM way 33271879 by adding 2400000000 to its OSM way id (in case of a relation that would be 3600000000). See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_element_id.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks ThomasG77. I found what I was looking for. On the website, it first resolves the extended queries, and then substitutes them. The extended queries get cached, so I wasn't seeing them initially.

The first bit gets the *place_id* from nomination:

```
curl 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?X-Requested-With=overpass-turbo&format=json&q=Ridgefield+Connecticut' -H 'Origin: http://overpass-turbo.eu' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
[{"place_id":"2578289456","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"305805056","boundingbox":["41.2371844","41.3774174","-73.5509631","-73.438191"],"lat":"41.2814842","lon":"-73.4981792","display_name":"Ridgefield, Fairfield County, Connecticut, United States of America","class":"boundary","type":"administrative","importance":0.62842337196131,"icon":"http:\/\/nominatim.openstreetmap.org\/images\/mapicons\/poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png"},{"place_id":"57921086","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"21923588","boundingbox":["42.2668794","42.2694486","-88.3335358","-88.3264975"],"lat":"42.2694329","lon":"-88.3290606","display_name":"Connecticut Trail, Holcombville Corners, McHenry County, Illinois, 60012, United States of America","class":"highway","type":"residential","importance":0.2}]
```